# How to fill an element 100% vertically with children only with CSS?

Tags: html, css

This is my layout page, this code will be used later with JavaScript. I'm trying to simplify the JavaScript part with a fine CSS styling.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.jGp_jan {
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#DDD;
    border:2px solid #000;
    padding:-1px;
    width:320px;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:6px;
    box-shadow:8px 8px 12px black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="jGp_jan" id="jGp_jan_img" style="top:8px; left:8px; width:640px; height:460px;">
    <div id="{cabecalho}" style="display:block; margin:0px; padding:2px; background-color:#666; border-radius:6px; height:22px;">
        <button id="{btnFechar}" style="float:left;"> X </button>
        <div id="{titulo}" style="float:left; font-weight:bold; color:#FFC;"></div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:100%; height:100%; margin-top:-22px; padding-top:22px;">
        <div id="{conteudo}" style="display:block; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; background-color:#FFF; margin-bottom:-22px;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If you open this page, will see the {conteudo} box blowing up by bottom of the whole window (the root div). The -22px bottom merging should decrease total height of that div, but it doesn't, why? Maybe this way won't work at all, I was thinking about putting {cabecalho} over {conteudo}, but not sure how. Don't want to solve only for this case because this occurs in other situations, looking for a generic solution.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I got some troubles with fiddle, this is a live example: http://www.gustavopi.ppg.br/temp/jan.img.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an answer here that inspired me to make this solution, it's gone, don't know why. As CSS is full of ways to the same point, if anybody wish to provide another approach, will be welcome. As nobody seams interested in this question, I'll check my own as right.

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
.jGp_jan {
    position:fixed;
    background-color:#DDD;
    border:2px solid #000;
    padding:-1px;
    width:320px;
    height:auto;
    border-radius:6px;
    box-shadow:8px 8px 12px black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div class="jGp_jan" id="jGp_jan_img" style="top:8px; left:8px; width:640px; height:460px;">
    <div id="{cabecalho}" style="display:inline; background-color:#666; border-radius:6px; height:22px; position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; right:0px;">
        <button id="{btnFechar}" style="float:left;"> X </button>
        <div id="{titulo}" style="float:left; font-weight:bold; color:#FFC;"></div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline; position:absolute; top:22px; left:0px; right:0px; bottom:0px;">
        <div id="{conteudo}" style="display:block; width:100%; height:100%; overflow:hidden; background-color:#FFF; border-radius:6px;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="jGp_jan_borda"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, [the live example](http://www.gustavopi.ppg.br/temp/jan.img2.html).

Now I can delete the JavaScript line that was manually doing the job!

Any comments and suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

On your {conteudo} div change the

margin-bottom: -22px;

to:

margin-top: -22px;

And add Overflow:hidden to the unnamed parent div of {conteudo}

Comment: This will lift the {conteudo} and the background of {cabecalho} is now covered (I'm updating the live example).